# Is this the best way to create an object in Scala based on a condition?

Tags: scala

I have a class `A` that has 2 apply functions.
The first takes 1 argument, the second takes 0 arguments.

When creating an object of this class, I want to call the first apply function if the argument is available. If the argument is null, I want to call the second apply function with no arguments.

Is this the cleanest way to do it?

```
val thisMayOrMayNotBeNull 

val obj = Option(thisMayOrMayNotBeNull).map(A(_)).getOrElse(A)
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems fine. However, when you have a `option.map(f).getOrElse(default)` you can `option.fold(default)(f)`.

Comment: Looks good to me, if it compiles. Remember that having `null`s in the first place might already indicate bad practice in Scala.

Comment: can't you have the constructor with one argument call the other one if the argument is null?